# How To Replicate WndProc For Windows Store App?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

This is the method i am trying to reconstruct on a Windows Store App. Is there any way to replicate it? This code below is a piece of Sample code from [**IDENTIVE**](http://www.indentive.se/).

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message aMessage)
{
    if (aMessage.Msg == TNFCWrapper.WM_NFC_NOTIFY)
    {
        string s = "";
        Int32 wParam = aMessage.WParam.ToInt32();
        switch (wParam)
        {
            case TNFCWrapper.NFC_NDEF_FOUND:
                s = "NFC_NDEF_FOUND  Size = " + aMessage.LParam.ToString();
                break;
            case TNFCWrapper.NFC_DEVICE_CHANGED:
                s = "NFC_DEVICE_CHANGED";
                break;
            case TNFCWrapper.NFC_UNKNOWN_SERVICE:
                s = "NFC_UNKNOWN_SERVICE";
                break;
            case TNFCWrapper.NFC_CONNECTED:
                s = "NFC_CONNECTED";
                break;
            case TNFCWrapper.NFC_DISCONNECTED:
                s = "NFC_DISCONNECTED";
                break;
            case TNFCWrapper.NFC_IDLE:
                s = "NFC_IDLE";
                break;
            default:
                s = "UNKNOWN";
                break;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

        if (wParam == TNFCWrapper.NFC_DEVICE_CHANGED) DeviceCountLabel.Text = aMessage.LParam.ToString();
        if (wParam == TNFCWrapper.NFC_NDEF_FOUND) ReadNDEF();
    }
```

Comment: [Developing a Windows Store app with NFC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2013/04/18/develop-a-cutting-edge-app-with-nfc.aspx).

Comment: Thanks but this API is only applicable if the NFC is built into the Device i am deploying on. In my case, i'm tapping into the NFC connected to the PC via a USB Dongle.

Comment: You cannot make this code work in a Store app.  Nor can you ship your USB dongle through the Store, it only distributes programs.  This needs to be a desktop app.

Comment: @hans-passant So in other words, unless the NFC reader is built into the device, it's impossible for the application to tap into any NFC capabilities despite having an external dongle attached to it?